# Adding google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled meta-data tag to Cordova AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, cordova, google-analytics, admob

I'm trying to add the google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled meta-data tag `<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />` to the application tag in my AndroidManifest.xml in my Cordova project but I can't find the correct way.

I think it should be something like:

```
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/meta-data" mode="merge" >
        <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
    </edit-config>
```

But this gives me an error:

`Unable to graft xml at selector "/manifest/application/meta-data" from "[MY_PROJECT_PATH]\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml" during config install`

I've tried a couple of other options too but they either give errors as well or they just don't put the tag in at all.

Does anybody have an idea how to add this tag (preferably without plugins or hooks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more trail and error but I finally found it!

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```